# Rest Assured status code validation with body message

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest-assured

So I would like to validate the statusvod the following request:

```
 given()...when().post("1.1.1.1").then().statusCode(200)
```

My problem is, that if the validation fails, it won't show the error message, just the difference between the status code 200<->400.

I would like to see the response body message too. 
How can I raise that too?

Comment: Have you tried logging all ? log().all()

Comment: Sadly didn't help, but thanks!